# Why am I not able to receive the "Curious" badge?

Tags: bug, badges

I was just going over the badges which I have received and I tried to track my next one. I found that I need to ask 5 well received questions on different days. My badge shows 7/5, but still it is in the recommended section. Why haven't I received the badge yet? (Picture attached) [image: Picture]

Answer (score 6):

You may have also posted some other poor questions (downvoted, deleted) leading to not having a positive question record. The formula for one's question record is given in this quote [from Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67399/387405):

> A positive question record means you don't have too many Closed, Negative, or Deleted questions overall. The formula is (TotalQuestions - Negative - Closed - Deleted) / TotalQuestions ≥ 0.5. Questions that qualify as Negative and Closed and Deleted count three times in this calculation!

So, to have a positive question record the left hand side of the formula must be at least 0.5.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that only one question counts (per day) even if the OP 
 posts, for example, three questions on the same day and they all receive upvotes. Only one will be counted for the badge to be awarded.